# How can I group single and loop operations in one try/except block with same condition?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I wonder if there is any way to group operations below in one try/except block. I use the same exception in both cases. I was trying to shorten this code, but nothing good comes to my mind. Here is example code:

```
def cast_values(values):
    try:
        values['Price'] = float(values['Price'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

    for field in ('Pages', 'Quantity', 'Discount'):
        try:
            values[field] = int(values[field])
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

I want all keys to be checked, doesn't matter how many exceptions will occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generalize your code by factoring out the pairing of a key to a particular type. There you can have a single loop with a single `try` statement that accommodates all your key/type pairs.

```
def cast_values(values):
    type_map = {
        'Price': float,
        'Pages': int,
        'Quantity': int,
        'Discount': int,
    }

    for key, type_ in type_map.items():
        type_ = types.get(key, int)
        try:
            values[key] = type_(values[key])
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

In this case, I would probably get rid of the `try` statement altogether, and simply *check* if the key is in `values`:

```
for key, type_ in type_map.items():
    if key not in values:
        continue
    values[key] = type_(values[key])
```

Comment: +1 for this. This is also very extendable to allow you to use lambda functions for custom converters. Small note, while your exceptionless code is identical to the original post, you probably want to catch any exceptions thrown by ```type_(...)``` as operations like ```int("non-numeric")``` can fail, and it sounds like the OP doesn't want that

Comment: Probably; I left that out since the OP wasn't already doing it. It may be that whatever calls `cast_values` is catching any `ValueError` that propagates.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want one try block you can try to refactor like this (this is overkill tbh):

```
def cast_dict(dict_, key, type_):
    try:
        dict_[key] = type_(dict_[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass

def cast_values(values):
    cast_dict(values, 'Price', float)
    for field in ('Pages', 'Quantity', 'Discount'):
        cast_dict(values, field, int)
```